# Conservation of Energy stored in electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-fields, energy-conservation

Let's say due to some particle process, an electron is created at time $t >0$. And from this moment on, the electric field will start to propagate to infinity at the speed of $c$. But we know that the energy stored in the electric field is proportional to the volume integral of $E^2$. Then wouldn't this mean more energy is being stored in the field as time passes? How is the total energy conserved and what offsets the continual increase in stored field energy?

Comment: Conservation of charge implies you'll also create a positive charge. Charge separation takes work, which goes into the field.

Comment: And also, the static electric field of an electron is present instantaneously. Virtual photons (constituting this static field) are taking care of this (a condensate).

Comment: If you create an electron out of nothing it is no surprise that energy is not conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lets say ... an electron is created* - there's your problem; you just violated charge conservation.

You can't create a single charge out of nothing.

You might create a *pair* of charges (e.g., by decay of a neutral boson), one positive and one negative, but then you'd have two opposing fields whose energy content would exactly balance.

Answer (score 0):

No energy conservation is not violated because for creating an electron,energy is required.In this case without specifying any source you have violated the law of conservation of charge.

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand ,you have asked that  as the field is propagating the volume enclosed is increasing and so the energy stored should also increase,
But this is wrong. 
Because the electric field is also decreasing as you are moving away .
Rememeber there is an E^2  term so its rapidly decreasing.